# How to check if dialog is displayed or display multiple dialogs of the same type?

Tags: android, dialog, showdialog

I'm managing dialogs by `showDialog`/`dismissDialog`/`removeDialog`.

I want to:

Display several dialogs in kind of a stack:

a) First dialog is shown using `showDialog(DIALOG_TYPE)`

b) Next dialogs are shown on top of the existing dialog

Now I'm only able to display first dialog using `showDialog` and then next dialogs are ignored.

Display last dialog:

a) First dialog is shown using `showDialog(DIALOG_TYPE)`

b) Application checks if dialog is displayed, closes dialog (if it's displayed) and opens a new dialog.

Is there any possibility to achieve one of the above solutions?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Dialog has an [isShowing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29) method that should return if the dialog is currently visible. So you can use that to see if a dialog is showing and hide it with dismissDialog(). You just have to keep a reference to the Dialogs you create in onCreateDialog().

Comment: Ok, this satisfies the first scenario, but what about stacking? Maybe there is some possibility to show several dialogs of the same type?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for stacking. If I stack multiple dialogs on top of each other, both have true for the showing property.

Comment: I don't know why calling *getDialog().isShowing()* from DialogFragment make it can't be showed, it's so crazy.

Comment: @PhongNguyen  DialogFragment has `isVisible()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use flag to check whether dialog is opened or not and according to flag value you can do whatever you want. Like I did. I am having only one dialog but when I touch another `EditText` and if my dialog is opened then it should close first and then should re-open with animation.

Code snippet:

```
    private EditText mEditText, mEditCode;
    private Dialog mDialog;
    private int mClicked = 0;
    private boolean isShown = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EnterValue);
        mEditText.setClickable(true);
        mEditText.setOnClickListener(this);

        mEditCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EnterCode);
        mEditCode.setClickable(true);
        mEditCode.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View nView)
    {
        switch (nView.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.EnterValue:
            mClicked = R.id.EnterValue;
            mEditText.requestFocus();
            mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            mEditText.setEnabled(true);
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().toString().trim().length());
            if(isShown)
            {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                showInfoDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                showInfoDialog();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.EnterCode:
            mClicked = R.id.EnterCode;
            mEditCode.requestFocus();
            mEditCode.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            mEditCode.setEnabled(true);
            mEditCode.setSelection(mEditCode.getText().toString().trim().length());
            if(isShown)
            {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                showInfoDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                showInfoDialog();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private boolean showInfoDialog() 
    {
        mDialog = new Dialog(CustomKeyboardNotLikeAndroidActivity.this, R.style.PauseDialog);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.keyboard);
        mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
        mDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        isShown = true;
        mDialog.show();
        return false;
    }
```

Try to alter this code in your way. Hope this can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`Dialog` implements `DialogInterface` which has `OnShowListener`.

Therefore you can use code like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
// ... set all things considering your dialog
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // do something when your dialog is shown    
    }
});
```